# FirebaseUI 3.1.2 dependency issue with firebase auth/firestore 11.8.0

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I have seen this issue talked about on the FirebaseUI documentation but for the life of me I cannot understand the solution.  I want to use the latest version of Firebase Auth and Firestore, as well as the latest version of FirebaseUI.  Is this possible?  Please do not just link me to the documentation of dependency issue, I would really appreciate an explanation of the documentation and what to actually write on my dependencies to fix this issue.  I am tempted to just write my own UI, but firebaseUI is too good to pass up.  Here are my dependencies right now:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'


    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'

    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.1.2'
}
```

With my past attempts at a fix I just tried lowering the versions of firebase..but that's not the solution I'm looking for and it usually just results in other errors.  Thank you so much in advance!

EDIT:  Here is error message: all gms/firebase libraries must use the exact same version specification(mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 11.8.0,11.6.2. 
Examples include com.google.android.gms:play0services-base:11.8.0 and com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.6.2.

{This error is, presumably, happening because firebaseui 3.1.2 is dependent on Firebase 11.6.2.  But the version I am trying to use is 11.8.0}

Comment: What's the problem you're having?  Do you have an error message to work with?

Comment: error message put in edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can exclude a dependencies' dependency with the `exclude` keyword.

```
implementation('com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.1.2') {
     exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
     exclude group: 'com.google.firebase'
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It did take away the error.  I hope the fact that it requires an earlier version won't lead to errors at runtime etc.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase SDK Version 11.8.0 released December 18, 2017, and there is no officially released FirebaseUI version for that release for now. You can see the corresponding versions of Firebase UI - Firebase Services at https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android

Corresponding FirebaseUI Version and Firebase/Play Services Versions are listed as:

3.1.2 --- 11.6.2

3.1.0 --- 11.4.2

3.0.0 --- 11.4.2

2.4.0 --- 11.4.0

...

This is why you get an error like :

`all gms/firebase libraries must use the exact same version specification(mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 11.8.0,11.6.2. Examples include com.google.android.gms:play0services-base:11.8.0 and com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.6.2.`

Answer (score 0):

Check if your

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:**26**.1.0'
```

version is same as your

```
targetSdkVersion **26**
```

Mine was different and changing this resolved the problem.